# How to enable a function only on clicking a particular condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi there i have 3 buttons called 1.ADD , 2.EDIT , 3.DELETE.....and a map with id=comp_map... and I am using Open Street Maps....

```
function addComp() {

     $("#comp_map").click(function() {
          if (event.type !== 'mousemove') {
                var containerPoint = comp_map.mouseEventToContainerPoint(event),
                layerPoint = comp_map.containerPointToLayerPoint(containerPoint),
                latlng = comp_map.layerPointToLatLng(layerPoint)            
                alert("Marker Location: "+latlng);
            }
    });


}

   function editComp() {
        // disable the map click
    }

    function delComp() {
        // disable the map click
    }
```

My question is i want `$("#comp_map").click` to work only when add button is clicked... but when the other buttons like edit , delete are clicked this function should not work... is this the right way to do this or if my approach is wrong please correct me... Thank You...!

Comment: So clicking on the map should call different functions depending on which button has most recently been clicked/is active? or do I misunderstand your intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to track the state of your application/buttons so that when the map is clicked you can handle the interaction differently depending on that state:

In your JS

```
$(function() {
  //set default action to add. If no default set action = false
  var action = 'add';
  //Bind to button clicks and update stored state
  $('body').on('click', 'button', function(e){
    var newAction = $(e.target).data('action');
    if ($(e.target).data('action')) {
      action = newAction;
    }
  });
  //bind to map clicks and handle based on current action state
  $("#comp_map").click(function(e) {
    //you might want this conditional in your addComp() fn depending on what you need in editComp()/delComp()
    if (e.type !== 'mousemove') {
      e.preventDefault();
      switch (action) {
         case "add": 
            addComp(e);
            break;
         case "edit":
            editComp(e);
            break;
         case "delete":
            delComp(e);
            break;
         default:
            return false
            break;
      }
    }
  })
  function addComp(e) {
      var containerPoint = comp_map.mouseEventToContainerPoint(event),
        layerPoint = comp_map.containerPointToLayerPoint(containerPoint),
        latlng = comp_map.layerPointToLatLng(layerPoint)            
        alert("Marker Location: "+latlng);
  }
  function editComp(e) {
      // disable the map click
  }
  function delComp(e) {
      // disable the map click
  }
});
```

Then in your HTML set data attributes for the actions you want to select (you could also set a `selected` class on click to show the current action:

```
<button data-action="add">Add</button>
<button data-action="edit">Edit</button>
<button data-action="delete">Delete</button>
```